# how to attach multiple images after getting it from action file to input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzoneJS to upload multiple file and then taking image name back from action file using Json_Encode to attach these name to input field for submitting these input fields with other input fields in form. I could do it for one image but couldnt get any way for multiple images(2 images).

```
<div class=" dropzone dz-clickable photoBox" id="addPhoto">
      <input type="hidden" id="img1">
      <input type="hidden" id="img2">   
</div>  

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; 
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#addPhoto", {
acceptedFiles:'image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png,image/gif',
url: 'uploadProImage.php',
maxFiles: 2, // Number of files at a time
maxFilesize: 2, //in MB
maxfilesexceeded: function(file) {
alert('You have uploaded more than 2 Image. Only the first two file will be uploaded!');
},      
addRemoveLinks: true,
removedfile: function(file) {
var _ref;
return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;  
},
success: function (response) {
var x = JSON.parse(response.xhr.responseText);
    $('#img1').attr('value',x.img);
    $('#img2').attr('value',x.img);
}
});


<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header('Content-type: application/json');
require_once('simpleImage_class.php');
$ds= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$dir= 'ProPics';
$targetPath = $dir . $ds;   
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

   $img_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

   $img_tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                    

   $img_ext = pathinfo($img_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

   $chng_name = 'img-'.time().rand(0,10).".".$img_ext;

   $array = array("img"=>$chng_name);

   echo json_encode($array);

   $targetFile =  $targetPath. $chng_name; 

   if(move_uploaded_file($img_tmp_name,$targetFile))
   {
   $image = new SimpleImage();
   $image->load($targetFile);
   $image->resizeToWidth(110);
   $image->resizeToHeight(140);
   $image->save($targetPath.'thumb-'.$chng_name);   
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with AJAX JSON.

When a file is uploaded, you should return a AJAX JSON response and the response JSON should have all info you need to use in view.

Then you should use the success method to use the JSON responce like this-

```
$(function() {
    Dropzone.options.uiDZResume = {
        success: function(file, response){
            //Do what you need to do with the JSON u have received
        }
    };
});
```

And surely you should parse JSON and put them in the actual view with [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) like this-

```
var array = JSON.parse(string);
array.forEach(function(object) {
   //do what u need to do
});
```

So whole JS code for response will be like this -

```
$(function() {
    Dropzone.options.uiDZResume = {
        success: function(file, response){
            var array = JSON.parse(string);
            array.forEach(function(object)
            {
                //do what u need to do
          });
        }
    };
});
```